# Setting up Mock Endpoints in Apache Camel with log:*

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, apache-camel

I have several routes that end with a log uri such as

```
<route>
    <from uri="someUri" />
    <to uri="someProcessor" />
    <to uri="log:SOME_LOG?level=INFO" />
</route>
```

I am using `CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner` to run my unit tests.

I want to be able to mock my log endpoints as MockEndpoint objects. I have tried to use

`@MockEndpoints("log:*")`

along with

```
end = MockEndpoint.resolve(camelContext, "log:SOME_LOG?level=INFO");
```

but that generates a ClassCastException cannot cast InterceptSendToEndpoint to MockEndpoint.

and also tried

```
@EndpointInject(uri="log:SOME_LOG?level=INFO")
MockEndpoint end;
```

but that also generates an IllegalArgumentException.

```
Invalid type: org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint which cannot be 
injected via @EndpointInject/@Produce for: Endpoint[log:SOME_LOG?level=INFO]
```

A workaround I've found is by prepending my log uri with "mock:" and using

`@EndpointInject(uri="mock:log:SOME_LOG?level=INFO)` and defining my route in xml with

```
<route>
    <from uri="someUri" />
    <to uri="someProcessor" />
    <to uri="mock:log:SOME_LOG?level=INFO" />
</route>
```

However I would like to get this to work by mocking my log: uris and not having to modify my route definitions in camel.xml.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

When you use `@MockEndpoints("log:*")`, the camel just create the mock endpoint for you, the mock endpoint uri should be `mock:log:THE_REMAINED`. You should be able to get the mock endpoint with below code:

```
end = MockEndpoint.resolve(camelContext, "mock:log:SOME_LOG?level=INFO");
```

Comment: Are you saying his config should be `<to uri="log:SOME_LOG"/>`, the annotation remains `@MockEnpoints("log:*")` but he needs to initialize with `end = MockEndpoint.resolve(camelContext, "mock:log:SOME_LOG?level=INFO")`?